# Creating dataframe based on conditions on other dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two dataframes: s-1 column, d-3 columns

```
s = {0: [0, 0.3, 0.5, -0.1, -0.2, 0.7, 0]}
d = {0: [0.1, 0.2, -0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0], 1: [0.3, 0.4, -0.7, 0, 0.8, 0, 0.1], 2: [-0.5, 0.4, -0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0]}
sd = pd.DataFrame(data=s)
dd = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
result = pd.DataFrame()
```

I want to get the result dataframe (1 column) based on values in those two:
1. When value in `sd = 0` then `0`
2. When value in `sd != 0` then check if for this row there is at least one non-zero value in dd, if yes - get avg of non zero values, if no return `OK`

Here is what I would like to get:

```
results:
0   0
1   -0,033
2   -0,333
3   0,5
4   0,65
5   OK
6   0
```

I know I can use `dd[dd != 0].mean(axis=1)` to calculate the mean of non zero values for the row but I don't know how to connect all these 3 conditions together

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.where` twice

```
np.where(sd[0]==0,0,np.where(dd.eq(0).all(1),'OK',dd.mask(dd==0).mean(1)))
Out[232]: 
array(['0', '0.3333333333333333', '-0.3333333333333333', '0.5', '0.65',
       'OK', '0'], dtype='<U32')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy.select`:

```
c1 = sd[0].eq(0)
c2 = dd.eq(0).all(1)

res = np.select([c1, c2], [0, 'OK'], dd.where(dd.ne(0)).mean(1))
pd.Series(res)
```

```
0                      0
1     0.3333333333333333
2    -0.3333333333333333
3                    0.5
4                   0.65
5                     OK
6                      0
dtype: object
```

Comment: Nice one :-)  np.select

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help. I managed to do it in a quite different way.
I used:

```
res1 = pd.Series(np.where(sd[0]==0, 0, dd[dd != 0].mean(axis=1))).fillna('OK')
```

The difference is that it returns float values (for rows that are not 'OK'), not string. It also appears to be a little bit faster.